# Angular. Контекстное меню

Tags: angular

Необходимо реализовать контекстное меню при нажатии правой клавишей мыши. Проект на Ангуляре от гугла.

```
<!-- Last Modified Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="modified">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      <div align="left">По дате изменения</div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextmenu" (contextmenu)="openContext()"> {{item.modified.slice(0,10)}} я </td>
  </ng-container>

openContext() {
this.triggerContext.openMenu();
}
```

Меню открывается при нажатии левой кнопки, а при нажатии правой не срабатывает!

Comment: во-первых что это такое `$event ? openContext() : null`? зачем нужна эта проверка? покажите код функции `openContext` и весь шаблон

Comment: openContext() {
    this.triggerContext.openMenu();
  }

Comment: Весь шаблон большой. Вот часть таблицы

Comment: <!-- Last Modified Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="modified">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
      <div align="left">По дате изменения</div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextmenu" (contextmenu)="openContext()"> {{item.modified.slice(0,10)}} я </td>
  </ng-container>

Comment: не в комментариях, а возле своего вопроса кнопка править)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подвоха ни в чем нету, `MatMenuTrigger` - из названия можно понять, что делает данная директива.

Я не знаю всего вашего шаблона, к тому же где находится меню, покажу на маленьком примере.

Для начала дизейблим событие `contextmenu` на документе:

```
// app.component.ts

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e: MouseEvent) => {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

В шаблоне создаем меню, тригер и кнопку для райт клика, в вашем случае в компоненте `mat-table`:

```
// app.component.html 

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>Кнопка меню</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Еще одна кнопка меню</button>
</mat-menu>

<button class="menu-trigger" mat-button #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger"  [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
    Это кнопка тригера
</button>

<button (contextmenu)="menuTrigger.openMenu()">
    Кликни меня правой клавишей
</button>
```

Самому тригеру добавляем класс `menu-trigger` для того, чтобы скрыть его в стилях, так как он по left клику открывает меню (что нам не нужно):

```
// app.component.scss

mat-table {
    .menu-trigger {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, единственно как сделать чтобы меню открывалось там, где я кликаю мышью?

Comment: ну вы же кликаете на кнопку, значит нужно `mat-menu` нужно поместить рядом с этой кнопкой

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо.